# Categorising symbology using more than one feature

Tags: qgis, symbology, print-composer, style-manager, wildlife-ecology

In my line of work I receive excel spreadsheets with records of notable/protected species in a particular area.

I would like to style them so that the shape denotes their Taxon Group, and their colour denotes their Common Name.

I realise I could separate the taxon groups out into different shapefile layers and style them that way, but I use 'point displacement' and don't want the points to stack on top of each other.

I have also tried using the field calculator to combine 'Taxon Group' and 'Common Name' but this changes how they appear in the key.

Answer (score 2):

Here I have used Rule-based symbology to define the shape (for the taxon). Then used the Data Defined Override for the symbol fill colour within each rule (for the common name). I had the colours added as an attribute in the table, but you could use an expression to define them.

- Double-click a rule to edit its symbology and choose your desired shape
- Then for the Fill Colour, click the data-defined override button and
  choose Edit:

[image]

My expression was just `"colour"` as I had already defined the colours in the attribute table using the field calculator. I did this for each of the 3 rules:

[image]

[image]

An example expression to define the colours:

```
CASE 
    WHEN "common_name" = 'grass snake' THEN 'lightblue'
    WHEN "common_name" = 'adder' THEN 'darkblue'
END
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it :

In the style tab, use *Categorized* and in the value,

`if count(concat("taxon group", "common name"))>0, concat("taxon group", ' - ', "common name"), null)`

Then, hit *Classify* and you should get a certain number of classes in random color where a combination of taxon group and common name can be found at least once.

For example, here I have geolocalized pictures classified by brand and model :
[image]

For the shape part, I don't know how to randomize that except by maybe using the geometry generator as a symbol or set up manually a shape for each taxon group/common name.

Answer (score 0):

Taking into account what you have already done, I find several options, I will start with the ones that could be simpler, although not for that reason better:

- Try to combine the fields in excel and not with the calculator.
- Use rule-based symbology.
- Try to do a multivariable analysis, I leave you a link to the guide, I know it exists but I haven't done it never. https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/vector_properties.html#proportional-symbol-and-multivariate-analysis